# No gradients provided for any variable for increasing Loss value inside tf.while_loop

Tags: python, tensorflow, optimization, while-loop

I have a CNN architecture, with consists of some layers -- convolution, fully-connected, and deconvolution -- (called it with **first process**). The last deconvolution layer gives me the points as the output and I need to do some processing (call it with **second process**) with this output to get the `Loss` value.

In the **second process**, I'm doing the `tf.while_loop` for calculating the `Loss` value, because the `Loss` value is achieved by adding all `Loss` values from each iteration in `tf.while_loop`. And I give the `tf.constant(0)` for the `Loss` initialization before looping.

When I tried to train and minimize that `Loss`, it shows me the error of **No gradient provided** between the output from **first process** and **Loss tensor**.

The **second process** looks like this:

```
loss = tf.constant(0)
i = tf.constant(0)

def cond(i, loss):
    return tf.less(i, tf.size(xy))

def body(i, loss):
    # xy is the output from the first process
    xy = tf.cast(xy, tf.float32)
    x = tf.reduce_mean(xy) 
    loss = tf.add(loss, x)
    return [tf.add(i,1), loss]
r = tf.while_loop(cond, body, [i, loss])

optimizer.minimize(r[1])
```

And I also do some processing inside the **second process** which (I read from many posts, especially [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/1511)) doesn't provide gradient.

Any help would be really appreciated.

Comment: There seem to be some typos in the code you provided. Like `def cond()` is just floating around and `r = tf.while_loop()` doesn't reference anything. Could you correct these mistakes and update the code otherwise it's not possible to help you.

Comment: @nitred I updated the code. It's not the full code because the full code is more complex. But, the global description about what I did in my code is explained in the post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's several reasons why you will get that error. Without actually seeing your original code it might be hard to debug but here's at least two reasons why gradients aren't provided:

1. There are some tensorflow operations through which gradients cannot flow or back-propagation cannot occur. For example `tf.cast` or `tf.assign` etc. In the post that you linked, there's a comment that mentions [this](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/1511#issuecomment-247719542). So in the example you provided `tf.cast` will definitely cause an issue.

   - A solution to this problem would be to restructure your code in such a way that you don't use tensorflow operations that disallow gradients to pass through them.
2. A second reason why this might occur is when you try to optimize variables by using a loss that was not calculated on those variables. For example, if you calculated loss in your **first process** on **conv1** variables, and then in your **second process** you try to update/optimize **conv2** variables. This will not work since the gradients will be calculated for **conv1** variables and not **conv2**.

It looks like in your case it is most likely the first issue and not the second one.